# How to create ".log" file in C?

Tags: c

I need to create .log file using C. However, I cannot use the usual way to create this. The file is created but it cannot write. Can anyone explain?

```
 f = fopen("file.log", "w"); 
 fprintf(f, "print this");
```

Comment: We can't explain unless you show what you were trying to do. Can we see the code?

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.  Perhaps we can help if you provide some additional information.

Comment: You're going to need to explain what you consider is the 'usual way' and what alternative you tried.  My best _guess_ would be that you used 'read-only' options on the file, but with no code to help us, the best we can do is vote to close the question 'insufficient information'.

Comment: Don't donwvote a stackoverflow beginner. Help him understand how stackoverflow works.

Comment: @Altar, that's been done already, but as the requested code hasn't been provided this is clearly downvote-worthy - without any code it is unclear and not useful. Such questions are downvoted and that's how SO works...

Comment: something like 
f = fopen("file.log", "w"); 
fprintf(f, "print this");

Comment: @kviiri-give the guy 1 minute. don't be so impatient.

Answer (score 14):

Well creating a .log file is just like creating any other file in C

```
FILE *f;
f = fopen("x.log", "a+"); // a+ (create + append) option will allow appending which is useful in a log file
if (f == NULL) { /* Something is wrong   */}
fprintf(f, "I'm logging something ...\n");
```

That is pretty much the whole magic.

Comment: Why would you need to update a log file?  Isn't `"a"` sufficient?

Comment: I guess you are right. I'll update my answer. But then again, it's impossible to know what the OP whants to do with that file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below code to create a file. But remember that File is created in the same folder where you have saved your code.

```
FILE *fp;
fp  = fopen ("data.log", "w");
fprintf(fp, "print this");
```

You can also specify the path where you want to create your file.

```
FILE *fp;
fp  = fopen ("E://data.log", "w");
fprintf(fp, "print this"); 
}
```